# Flutter Workmanager cannot get location from Geolocator in background

Tags: flutter, dart

I use Workmanager get location from Geolocator in background with this code.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:geolocator/geolocator.dart';
import 'package:workmanager/workmanager.dart';

late LocationSettings locationSettings;

const fetchBackground = "fetchBackground";

@pragma('vm:entry-point')
void callbackDispatcher() {
  Workmanager().executeTask((task, inputData) async {
    switch (task) {
      case fetchBackground:
        try {
          Position position = await Geolocator.getCurrentPosition();
          print(
              'Latitude: ${position.latitude}, Longitude: ${position.longitude}');
        } catch (error) {
          print('Error getting position: $error');
        }
        break;
    }
    return Future.value(true);
  });
}

void main() {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  Workmanager().initialize(callbackDispatcher);
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'MyApp Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(

        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({super.key, required this.title});

  final String title;

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {


  Future<Position> _determinePosition() async {
    bool serviceEnabled;
    LocationPermission permission;

    // Test if location services are enabled.
    serviceEnabled = await Geolocator.isLocationServiceEnabled();
    if (!serviceEnabled) {

      return Future.error('Location services are disabled.');
    }

    permission = await Geolocator.checkPermission();
    if (permission == LocationPermission.denied) {
      permission = await Geolocator.requestPermission();
      if (permission == LocationPermission.denied) {

        return Future.error('Location permissions are denied');
      }
    }

    if (permission == LocationPermission.deniedForever) {
      // Permissions are denied forever, handle appropriately.
      return Future.error(
          'Location permissions are permanently denied, we cannot request permissions.');
    }

    // When we reach here, permissions are granted and we can
    // continue accessing the position of the device.
    return await Geolocator.getCurrentPosition();
  }

  void _getPosition() async {
    try {
      Position position = await _determinePosition();
      print('Latitude: ${position.latitude}, Longitude: ${position.longitude}');
      // Do whatever you want with the position data here.
    } catch (error) {
      print('Error getting position: $error');
      // Handle the error appropriately, show feedback to the user, etc.
    }
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    // Call _getPosition() when the page is initialized
    _getPosition();

    Workmanager().initialize(
      callbackDispatcher,
      isInDebugMode: true,
    );
    // Schedule the background location update task using Workmanager
    Workmanager().registerPeriodicTask(
      "backgroundLocationTask",
      fetchBackground,
      frequency: Duration(seconds: 10),
      //frequency: Duration(minutes: 15), // Set every 15 minutes
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        // Here we take the value from the MyHomePage object that was created by
        // the App.build method, and use it to set our appbar title.
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

It have no error when run in foreground but when run in background it show error like this.

```
D/FlutterGeolocator(19802): Disposing Geolocator services
E/FlutterGeolocator(19802): Geolocator position updates stopped
D/FlutterGeolocator(19802): Stopping location service.
I/WM-WorkerWrapper(19802): Work [ id=fc438a55-d63a-47e7-836e-5e0bfac59d2d, tags={ be.tramckrijte.workmanager.BackgroundWorker } ] was cancelled
I/WM-WorkerWrapper(19802): java.util.concurrent.CancellationException: Task was cancelled.
I/WM-WorkerWrapper(19802):  at androidx.work.impl.utils.futures.AbstractFuture.cancellationExceptionWithCause(AbstractFuture.java:1184)
I/WM-WorkerWrapper(19802):  at androidx.work.impl.utils.futures.AbstractFuture.getDoneValue(AbstractFuture.java:514)
I/WM-WorkerWrapper(19802):  at androidx.work.impl.utils.futures.AbstractFuture.get(AbstractFuture.java:475)
I/WM-WorkerWrapper(19802):  at androidx.work.impl.WorkerWrapper$2.run(WorkerWrapper.java:311)
I/WM-WorkerWrapper(19802):  at androidx.work.impl.utils.SerialExecutor$Task.run(SerialExecutor.java:91)
I/WM-WorkerWrapper(19802):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
I/WM-WorkerWrapper(19802):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
I/WM-WorkerWrapper(19802):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:919)
D/FlutterGeolocator(19802): Unbinding from location service.
D/FlutterGeolocator(19802): Destroying location service.
D/FlutterGeolocator(19802): Stopping location service.
D/FlutterGeolocator(19802): Destroyed location service.
```

How to fix it?

Comment: Did you set the required permissions for background location?

For Android, 
The system dialog doesn't include the Allow all the time option. Instead, users must enable background location on a settings page.

Comment: I set <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION"/> in AndroidManifest already. I don't know why it show error

Comment: The thing is that even if you set the background location permission in the manifest, the permission request dialog does not show the option (SDK >= 29) to allow location in the background. You need to manually set it from settings (AppInfo->Permissions)